# Create CBitmap from CDC?

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi, brush, cbitmap

Using C++/MFC and GDI (not GDI+), the overall goal is to create an patterned `HBRUSH`, which will be used in `OnCtlColor` to outline an edit control in red, with the ability to turn the outline on and off. To do this, you attach a bitmap to an `HBRUSH` using `CreatePatternBrush`. Here is the code for doing that, using a stored bitmap resource:

```
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
BOOL ok = redBoxBitmap.LoadBitmap(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_mespe_EditBox_Red));
ok = redBoxBrush.CreatePatternBrush(&redBoxBitmap);
```

and in `OnCtlColor`

```
HBRUSH CModelEditorSpecies::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    HBRUSH hbr;
    int ctrlID=pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID();
    if(ctrlID==IDC_MyEditControl)
        hbr=(HBRUSH) redBoxBrush;
    else
        hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    return hbr;
}
```

The above code all works as desired. However, it depends on the bitmap being sized to the edit control. What I need now is the ability to create the bitmap within the C++ program, sized to the client area of the control, which depends on both the design size of the control (in the dialog editor), and the user's setting of text size in Windows 10 settings.

I cannot find a straightforward way of either constructing a bitmap, or, better, creating an empty one of the proper size (can do), selecting it into a `CDC` (can do), drawing the red box into it (can do), then extracting the update bitmap from the `CDC` (how to do?).

Can anyone suggest either how to create the bitmap programmatically, or suggest a better method of getting an edit control boxed in red when the program calls for that?

**Added in response to @Constantine Georgiou's answer of 3/9:**

New code:

```
CBitmap redBoxBitmap; // member variables of class CModelEditorSpecies
CBrush redBoxBrush;

BOOL CModelEditorSpecies::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    BOOL ok;
    CRect r; defaultSpecies1Ctrl.GetClientRect(&r);
    xx(r.Width(), r.Height()/*, redBoxBrush*/);
    ok = redBoxBrush.CreatePatternBrush(&redBoxBitmap);
    //...
}

void CModelEditorSpecies::xx(const int w, const int h)
{
    CDC *pDC=GetDC();
    redBoxBitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, w, h);
    
    // Create a red pen
    CPen redPen;
    redPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    
    // Draw the bitmap - red pen & default background brush
    CBitmap *pOldBitmap=pDC->SelectObject(&redBoxBitmap);
    pDC->SelectObject(&redPen);
    CBrush editBoxBrush;
    editBoxBrush.CreateSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);
    pDC->SelectObject(&editBoxBrush);
    pDC->Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
        
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldBitmap);
    
    // Create the edit-control custom brush
    redBoxBrush.CreatePatternBrush(&redBoxBitmap);
    return;
}
```

This code produces an all-black edit control, as if the bitmap being used were monochrome. That would be expected if drawing in the dc does not affect the bitmap, or, if drawing in a dc-compatible bitmap does not use the colors in `redPen` and `editBoxBrush`, as suggested by @IInspectable.

Comment: Using the `WM_CTLCOLOR` (or the `OnCtlColor()`) event affects the background of the edit-control, not the outline. I guess what you have done so far is create a bitmap of size equal to the control's client area, with the edges colored red and create a pattern brush with that. You can simply create the bitmap using `CreateCompatibleBitmap()`, fill it with the background brush and call `MoveTo()/LineTo()` to draw the outline. The brush can be "cached" (created once, and destroyed only when the dialog class instance is destroyed).

Comment: Alternative implementations to consider: 1. Process the `WM_NCPAINT` message, and perform custom painting for the border of the control instead. 2. Process the `WM_PAINT` message **for the dialog** (`CModelEditorSpecies::OnPaint()`) to draw a frame **around** the control (`FrameRect()` function).

Comment: @Constantine Georgiou: Your first comment suggests creating the bitmap, but what is in this bitmap? Background color is white. `OnCtlColor()` uses the brush to fill the control, but there is no opportunity to draw the red border lines. I am already caching the brush, as you see in the existing code.

Comment: You can create a memory device context (`CreateCompatibleDC`), select your bitmap into it, perform your rendering, and select the bitmap back out of it prior to tearing it down. Your bitmap now contains whatever you rendered onto it. I'm not convinced that you can use alpha transparency with a pattern brush, though, in case that is required.

Comment: Before I posted, when I tried creating a `memDC`, selecting bitmap in, drawing, and selecting out, I got an all-black bitmap. I will try that again.

Comment: That happens when you create the compatible bitmap off of the compatible DC. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap): *"When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, the bitmap that is created is a **monochrome** bitmap."*

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to create the brush - used the Win32 functions instead of their MFC wrappers, but you can figure it out.

```
BOOL CModelEditorSpecies::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Get edit-control's size
    RECT rc;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_MyEditControl)->GetClientRect(&rc);

    // Create the bitmap and a memory-DC
    HDC hDC = ::GetDC(HWND_DESKTOP);
    HDC mDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, rc.right, rc.bottom);
    ::ReleaseDC(HWND_DESKTOP, hDC);

    // Create a red pen
    HPEN hPen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));

    // Draw the bitmap - red pen & default background brush
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(mDC, hBmp);
    HPEN hOldPen = (HPEN) SelectObject(mDC, hPen);
    HBRUSH hOldBr = (HBRUSH) SelectObject(mDC, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
    Rectangle(mDC, rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, rc.bottom);
    SelectObject(mDC, hOldBr);
    SelectObject(mDC, hOldPen);
    SelectObject(mDC, hOldBmp);

    // Create the edit-control custom brush
    redBoxBrush = CreatePatternBrush(hBmp);

    // Clean-up - the SysColorBrush doesn't need to be deleted
    DeleteObject(hPen);
    DeleteObject(hBmp);
    DeleteDC(mDC);

    return TRUE;
}

HBRUSH CModelEditorSpecies::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    return (nCtlColor == CTLCOLOR_EDIT && pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID() == IDC_MyEditControl) ?
        redBoxBrush : CDialogEx::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
}
```

Also check the alternatives I suggested in the comments. This one will be drawing into the edit-control's client area.

---

**EDIT:**

The code I posted above does work, and after it runs all left is the `HBRUSH` handle (pattern-brush for your edit box). I can't see why you insist using the MFC wrappers instead. They are "higher-level" thin wrappers, so... "thin" actually, that you still have to perform almost exactly the same operations (create, select into a DC, perfrom some drawing operation, select out of the DC) as the GDI ones. The only operation you don't need to perform is delete the resource (the object's destructor will call `DeleteObject()` for you).

Anyways, if you prefer MFC over GDI, let's see what's wrong with your code. It has quite a few issues:

- First and foremost, you need a [memory DC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/memory-device-contexts) to draw on a bitmap, the window DC you get by calling `GetDC()` draws on a window's surface.
- The DC you get by calling `GetDC()` must be returned to the system (`ReleaseDC()`), because `pDC` is just a pointer, and the compiler won't call the destructor.
- The objects you select into a DC must be selected out before it is destroyed, otherwise memory-leaks may be occurring.

So your code should be changed as shown below:

```
void CModelEditorSpecies::xx()
{
    CRect r;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_MyEditControl)->GetClientRect(&r);
    
    // Create the bitmap and a memory-DC
    CBitmap redBoxBitmap;
    CDC mDC, *pDC = GetDC();
    redBoxBitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, r.Width(), r.Height());
    mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    ReleaseDC(pDC);

    // Create a red pen and get the default background brush
    CPen redPen;
    redPen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(255, 0, 0));
    CBrush editBoxBrush;
    editBoxBrush.CreateSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);

    // Draw the bitmap - red pen & default background brush
    CBitmap *pOldBitmap = mDC.SelectObject(&redBoxBitmap);
    CPen *pOldPen = mDC.SelectObject(&redPen);
    CBrush *pOldBrush =mDC.SelectObject(&editBoxBrush);
    mDC.Rectangle(r);
    mDC.SelectObject(pOldBrush);
    mDC.SelectObject(pOldPen);
    mDC.SelectObject(pOldBitmap);

    // Create the edit-control custom brush
    redBoxBrush.CreatePatternBrush(&redBoxBitmap);
}
```

It's basically the same as the GDI version.

Comment: Your MFC code works perfectly. I was incorrectly assuming `GetDC` returned a memory DC. Tnx for your patience. BTW, I am using MFC for this because the remainder of the project uses it.